# Is it possible to have UITabBarItem without image, but with bigger text instead?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder

Is it possible to have UITabBarItem without image, but with bigger text instead?

e.g.: to have text with full height?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just make an image of the larger text. As far as I know, that's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can initialise it with an empty image like this:

```
 UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
 tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:image tag:tag] ;
 [image release];
```

Only the title text will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Full solution is here.

You need to set empty image to tabBarItem. Otherwise tabBarItem will not appear until you tap it.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        self.tabBarItem.title = @"Report";
        self.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage alloc] init];

    }

    return self;
}
```

Customization of UITabBar:

```
- (void)customizeAppearance
{
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                                         NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:22]}
                                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName:RGB(0xff9700),
                                                         NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:22]}
                                             forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0, -10.0)];
}
```